# Open Text File in the root directory

Tags: c++, file-io

I have made a simple scoring system which upon correct answer, stores the numbers of the player in the file.
I have used the file name like this :

```
ofstream outfile ("C:\Aadam\Desktop\Project\Scores.txt",ios::app);
```

But the problem with this approach is that what if I move the program over to a USB and try to run it in another computer. Now it will look in the directory I specified above but there is no **Scores.txt** file in there.
What I want to do is to give it a path which is in the **project** folder. So when I move the program, it shouldn't make a difference because I will move the whole project folder.
Of course I can do this :

```
ofstream outfile ("Scores.txt",ios::app)
```

which will always look in the project directory and it will work fine as long as I run the program from the **IDE** but what if I run the program from the **.exe** file which is two directories down like

> "C:\Aadam\Desktop\Project\bin\Debug\Project.exe"

Now in this case, it can't open the file.
So if you know a good way to open files and kindly, Show me the Way.....

Comment: You may want to use forward slashes because `'\a'` is the escape code for alarm or bell.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse argv[0] (it will contain path used to invoke your executable - absolute or relative) and replace executable name in it with "Scores.txt"

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more, cause I am really a beginner in C++ programming so I don't exactly know what you are saying :)

Comment: Your main function should look like 'int main(int argc, const char* argv[])' argc tells you number of elements in argv array. argv[0] always contains executable name as it was invoked (full path, relative path, or executable name only). So you need to split directory part from it correctly and append "Scores.txt" to open file along with executable. If argv[0] contains only executable name or relative path that is relative to current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to pass the file path to program as an argument.

When you run a program from IDE, the project directory is considered as current working directory. If the program is run from the command line, the current working directory is from where the command is being run.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the exe file,`ofstream outfile ("Scores.txt",ios::app)` will create a file named "Scores.txt" in the same directory as your program.

Comment: If the program is started from the directory that differs from one containing an executable, the file would be created in the former one. One simple possible solution is to chdir/cd to the latter one before invocation.

Comment: I meant double clicking the exe